# PCL transform TextureMesh before adding to the viewer

Tags: textures, transform, pcl

With PCL I'm loading an textured OBJ file to `pcl::TextureMesh`, and visualize it in a pcl viewer with the `viewer->addTextureMesh()` function.
Before visualizing the mesh, I need to transform it. For actual point cloud formats like `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` transformations are quite simple with the `pcl::transformPointCloud()` function. How could I transform a `pcl::TextureMesh`?

So far, I tried to get it into a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::TextureMesh>` (so I can use the `pcl::transformPointCloud()` function), but my PCL programmer skills are quite limited, so I'm not sure how to do that. To add it after the transformation to the viewer via the `viewer->addTextureMesh()` function I would need to extract it again from the `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::textureMesh>`, where again wouldn't know yet how.

Could anyone help me on how to transform a `pcl::TextureMesh`?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In polygon mesh, each polygon are attached with vertices by vertex index. When the vertex coordinates change (`mesh.cloud` in PCL), the mesh also changes.

However, the data type of `mesh.cloud` is [`pcl::PointCloud2`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/structpcl_1_1_texture_mesh.html) and [`pcl::transformPointCloud`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__common.html#ga52d532f7f2b4d7bba78d13701d3a33d8) does not support this data type. Therefore, we need to convert `pcl::PointCloud2` to `pcl::PointCloud<PointT>` before transformation.

Below is an example of my solution to transform mesh in PCL. It use `pcl::PolygonMesh` ( because I don't have OBJ file with texture), but I think it works fine with `pcl::TextureMesh`!

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <pcl/common/transforms.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
  string filepath = "test.obj";
  //// read mesh
  pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
  if (pcl::io::loadPolygonFile(filepath, mesh)==-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, " [ERROE] Could not read mesh from file %s\n", filepath.c_str());
    exit(1);
  }
  //// visualize before transformation
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer_(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("results"));
  viewer_->setBackgroundColor(0,0,0);
  viewer_->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
  viewer_->initCameraParameters();
  viewer_->addPolygonMesh(mesh, "mesh");
  viewer_->spin();
  //// convert to pcl::PointCloud<PointT>
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(mesh.cloud, cloud);
  //// transformation
  Matrix4f T = Matrix4f::Identity();
  T.block<3, 3>(0, 0) = AngleAxisf(M_PI/4, Vector3f(0,0,1)).toRotationMatrix();    // Rotate 45 degrees around the z-axis
  pcl::transformPointCloud(cloud, cloud, T);
  pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(cloud, mesh.cloud);
  //// visualize after transformation
  viewer_->updatePolygonMesh(mesh, "mesh");
  viewer_->spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the visualization results:

[visualize before transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YaTu.png)

[visualize after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLUGJ.png)